# hadoop RC file format : merge small files in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, file-format

I am seeking for way of combining small RC files generated by Map-reduce program.
What is best of going merge of small RC files to large one RC files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getmerge command . This takes a source directory and a destination file as input and concatenates files in source directory into the destination file.

Example , if Hive table name is search_combined_rc, you can get the combined rc file into a single file.

hadoop fs -getmerge /user/hive/warehouse/dev.db/search_combined_rc/ /localdata/destinationfilename

Since RCFile’s cannot be opened with the tools that open typical sequence files, you can try using **rcfilecat** tool to display the contents of RCFiles. you need to move back the file from local directory to HDFS.

hive --service rcfilecat /hdfsfilelocation

Comment: did this work? I think there may be another way where you can have all  in one file by setting the number of reducer 1 .